# Streamlit does not display the FastAPI through iframe

Tags: python, docker, streamlit

I'm having trouble running a FastAPI application in Streamlit.

I want to integrate the knowledge graph application as one of the pages in Streamlit (for presentation purposes, to make it more readable). However, the knowledge graph application has its own UI, which is why I wanted to display it through an iframe.

**The application is visible at localhost:8080** and is added as a page in the Streamlit application at localhost:8051. However, when accessing the page related to the graph in Streamlit, nothing is visible, no UI - just a blank Streamlit page.

The command docker exec -it streamlit-ui curl http://graph-ui:8080 successfully returns the content for me.
The application runs correctly on localhost:8080. The Streamlit application runs correctly on localhost:8501. All containers are running correctly. After accessing the appropriate pages in Streamlit, there is nothing visible (an empty Streamlit with a sidebar menu).

**If I replace the API_HOST in the following file with a different link (e.g., as in this [streamlit doc](https://docs.streamlit.io/streamlit-community-cloud/share-your-app/embed-your-app)), nothing is displayed either. Therefore, the issue is not with the graph-related application but somewhere else.**

**Page in Streamlit's pages related to the graph:**

```
import os
import streamlit as st

API_HOST = "http://graph_container_name:8080"

def app():
    st.title("FastAPI Integration with Streamlit")
    
    # Adding an iframe component embedding the FastAPI application.
    st.markdown(f'<iframe src="{API_HOST}" width="100%" height="600"></iframe>', unsafe_allow_html=True)
```

**main.py in the graph folder:**

```
app = FastAPI()


app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=["*"],
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)

...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import uvicorn
    uvicorn.run(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)
```

**Graph Dockerfile:**

```
FROM python:3.11.4-slim-bullseye

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt

RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y pkg-config gcc


RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

RUN pip install -U matplotlib

COPY . .

CMD ["python", "main.py"]
```

**Streamlit Dockerfile:**

```
FROM python:3.11.4-slim-bullseye

WORKDIR /app

COPY streamlit_ui/requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
COPY graph/requirements.txt /app/graph_requirements.txt

RUN apt-get update -y

RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir -r graph_requirements.txt

COPY streamlit_ui/ .
COPY graph/ /app/graph/

CMD ["streamlit", "run", "App.py", "--server.port", "8501"]
```

**fragment of docker-compose.yaml:**

```
  llm-s:
    build:
      context: llm_s
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: llm-s
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    environment:

    depends_on:
      - "standalone"
    networks:
      - llm_network

  streamlit-ui:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: streamlit_ui/Dockerfile
    container_name: streamlit-ui
    ports:
      - "8501:8501"
    environment:
      - API_NETWORK_HOST=http://myapi:8000
    depends_on:
      - "llm-s"
    networks:
      - llm_network

  graph:
    build:
      context: ./graph
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: graph-ui
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    environment:
      - API_NETWORK_HOST=graph-ui:8080
    depends_on:
      - "llm-s"
    networks:
      - llm_network



networks:
  llm_network:
    driver: bridge
```